# Is there a way to not allow a custom permalink on a certain URL?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

Got a question about permalinks, is it possible to add a function or filter to not allow a certain URL to be rewrote when a user has setup custom permalinks. For instance:

This URL can't be allowed:

http://domain.com/page/2/?search-listings=true

It needs to always be:

http://domain.com/?search-listings=true&paged=2

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WordPress provides some hooks and filters for URL generation,
see http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite#Plugin_Hooks

Comment: This is the right approach. You'll need to setup your own rewrite rule that has a higher priority that the core rule.

Comment: Ok, cool yeah I was looking at that yesterday gotta brush up on my regex.

Comment: Tried this http://pastie.org/9085811 but its not working, this kinda stuff is kinda beyond me never really got into it rewrites and regex, etc… instead of the ID how would it dynamically insert the page number?